# How to amicably discuss how rent will be increasing to newly inherited tenants?

Tags: united-states, conflict-aversion, approach

I already have a property where I inherited tenants, and increased rent. Although, it was only by $50 after six months. I also gave them a list of improvements to be done.

I'm looking at acquiring a larger property where rent is currently $550, and will need to be bumped up to $650 (at least). I cannot afford to wait six months. It would need to be increased as soon as their lease renews. From the wording of the listing, it sounds one or two month leases. Then, rent will increase by about 3% annually; it will increase by $20 every year.

One of the more service jobs I had growing up was as a camp counselor. I learned that talking to all the campers with a speech about how I was there for them always made the week go smooth. I said something along the lines of how they could come to be about anything.

It got me thinking about how when I was renting, I become irrationally angry when my rent was to increase by some marginal amount after a year (like $50). No doubt, I expect such emotions to happen with my future inherited tenants.

Any tips on how to break it to them firm but honest? I am not worried about tenants disliking me. I am not trying to make friends. I just want the transition to go smoothly, and ideally to keep long-term good tenants.

Lastly, I will give them a written notice too. I'm thinking this will be done before I talk with them face-to-face.

Comment: You say you cannot afford to wait six months. Is there a legal limit that requires you to wait for six months, or is this just something that you mention because you waited six months for the first property? What does the 3% increase annually have to do with this, is this also currently not in the lease contracts for the second property, and are you adding that too? Are you sure that what you're planning to do (increasing rent by over 18 percent in one go) is even legal to do?

Comment: There is no time limit in my state. I just mentioned that because of the first property. I do not need to stipulate rent increases in the lease. It is information I could or could not give them. And yes, there is no limit to how much rent can be increased in my state.

Comment: That's good! And do you have a rationale for increasing the rent, that you could/would be willing to share with the current renters? Since you say it "will need" to be bumped to "at least" 650, it sounds like there's a reason? Could the increase be negotiable for you, somehow?

Comment: It is median fair market rent. I would rather not disclose the rationale. It is about the ROI the property needs to garner. For my current property, with management, the ROI is only about 6%. Some would consider that a bad investment. (But in that case, I needed a place to lay my head.)

Comment: you want to buy a property whose current rent doesn't justify the price you have to pay for it, and your solution to that is to pay whatever the seller wants and raise the rent to meet that "need" for ROI, and you expect your tenants to be happy about that? If the current rent doesn't meet your ROI, either the price or your ROI "needs" are too high.

Comment: @KateGregory If the current rents are below the market rents for the area, and the local laws allow raising rents, why is it unreasonable to move the rents up towards market values?

Comment: It may or may not be unreasonable to do something you feel like doing and are not prohibited from doing. But to buy something for more than it is worth to you, planning to increase that worth by just raising prices, feels unfair and dishonest to me, all the more so when it is phrased as a "need". If OP wants to say "I can do this, and I would enjoy the extra money so I'm going to do it" that is at least honest. A position of "it's out of my hands, I have to do it to meet my ROI needs" when the person chose how much to invest knowing the current rent didn't bring that return ... feels false.

Comment: It's not unfair or dishonest in the least. Fair market rent is just that: fair. There is usually just less vacancy with below fair market rent. That's why many landlords do not raise rent over long periods of time in order to minimize vacancy/turnover. Whether you or I believe it is unfair or not, a critique or ethics discussion about the morality of raising rent, is not relevant.

Comment: @KateGregory, I think it depends whether the price of the new property is according to current market value. If it's on current market value, then indeed the rent fee needs to be updated. Consider the current owner of the new property. They can choose to sell the property with the new (higher) price to OP, or they can themselves increase the rent. If the current owner increases to rent price according to market value, do you feel anything wrong with that? How about the current owner selling it to OP first, and then OP increases the rent?

Comment: But the current market value is calculated from the rent it currently earns, @justhalf. If the OP was unable to raise the rent, presumably the purchase would not happen at the asking price.

Comment: @KateGregory I guess this is where we used different definitions. I take it that market value is defined as the price at which buyers are generally willing to buy (for buy market value) or rent (for rent market value) similar properties. For example, I once lived on a property whose owner lived overseas, and apparently had enough income, so didn't really update the rent fee for some good 12+ years. Obviously the rent is so far below the rent of other properties in the area, since other properties' rent had increased in the past 12 years. I wouldn't say that this cheap rent is the market value.

Comment: It is the current *price* set by the owner, and we say that the current price set by the owner is below the market value. If market value is determined by the current rent, then it doesn't really make sense to say something is below market value, yet people use that phrase all the time, to indicate what the property could have worth if left open in the free market.

Comment: I would give as much advance notice as possible, and as little explanation as possible. This is your decision, and no matter how they react, your decision is not going to change. Be pleasant but don't give them any opportunity to enter into a debate with you.  (Posting as a comment because my answer was deleted.)

Comment: After giving "written notice," landlords do not generally "talk with them face-to-face." Writing is serious, talking is dragging out the pain.

Answer (score 4):

I was a landlord for many years.  I've done exactly this many times.

> Any tips on how to break it to them firm but honest?

First thing to keep in mind, this is not a personal matter, **it is a business and legal matter.**

So, paperwork first.  Learn about, review, talk to your lawyer about the notification requirements in your jurisdiction and the current lease.  Find online a sample Notice of Rent Increase form (that complies with local law).  Complete and mail/deliver/post the day it's required or just before.

Now that they have been legally notified (you do this to protect yourself most of all)...

> Lastly, I will give them a written notice too. I'm thinking this will be done before I talk with them face-to-face.

You don't have to talk to them about it.**  If they accept the increase, all good.  No reason to create an opportunity for them to make demands.  *It's none of their business why you're increasing the rent*.  (Remember folks, this is business not personal.)

> I am not worried about tenants disliking me. I am not trying to make friends

Good!  For the former, you just want mutual respect and the latter, you don't want to.

> I just want the transition to go smoothly, and ideally to keep long-term good tenants.

If they do want to negotiate, it's just another business negotiation.  Know what you'll accept ahead of time, considering the current rental market and your ability to turn the property.  Be firm, polite and prepared for you or them to walk away.

While there may be no limit on the increase in your location, that just means you need to do your homework on the current market because if the increase is too high, they definitely will.

**If you plan on being a landlord for the long term, you could talk to them just to experience the interaction, even if it's not needed.  That's entirely up to you.

### Disclaimer:

Landlord/Tenant law isn't that complicated, but **this is not legal advice.** You have to know the prevailing law and comply. **Talk to a lawyer if you're not sure.**